# PHP how to split an array in variables

Tags: php, arrays, input, field, var

Hi everybody i need help! I've starting to learn php some week ago.
i have a form that POST some text field for a contact, i need to split the array in some variables to put in a email. this is my code

```
$field  = $_POST['input'];
if ( isset( $field ) === TRUE){

foreach ($field as $key => $value) {

    echo '<pre>' , print_r( $value ) , '</pre>'; //to list the array

    }

    $to = $mail;
    $sbj = "thanks to register to $site";
    ..//some headers
    mail($to,sbj,$headers)

}
```

and this is the form

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="input[]">
 <input type="text" name="input[]">
 <input type="text" name="input[]">
 <input type="submit" value="invia">
</form>
```

any suggestion for retrive the variables on the array to include on the mail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@John has given the right procedure . You can use another procedure by using [array_push()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) function eg:

```
$field  = $_POST['input'];
$info =  array();

foreach ($field as $key => $value) {
 array_push($info,$value);
}

// echo implode(",",$info);
$to = $mail;
$sbj = "thanks to register to $site";
$body = implode(",",$info);
..//some headers
mail($to,sbj,$body,$headers)
```

Comment: it's the same if i use input type="file" for input?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function , which takes an array and a separator  and joins the elements of the array together into a string, with each element separated by the separator string you pass it eg:

```
foreach($field as $key=>$value) {
    $input[] = $value;
}

$body = implode("\n",$input); //implode here

$to = $mail;
$sbj = "thanks to register to $site";
..//some headers
mail($to,sbj,$body,$headers)
```

This would create your list of input each on a separate line in the email.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest, but most ugly way to to this is just using:

```
mail($to,sbj,print_r($field, true),$headers);
```

`print_r($field, true)` will output the value to a variable and not print it out immediately.